# XmlSlurpur The prefix "something" for element "something:element" is not bound

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I am using XmlSlurper like so:

```
  def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlObj.lensData).declareNamespace(something:'something')
```

when i slurp the following xml it give an error:

```
 <something:Data>
      <something:Requirements>
            <something:Type>
                <something:Value>T</something:Value>
                <something:Label>TYP</something:Label>
            </something:Type>
      </something:Requirements>
 </something:Data>
```

the error i get is:

```
The prefix "something" for element "something:Data" is not bound.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: The prefix "something" for element "something:Data" is not bound.
```

I don't really understand what t do to fix this.
Any ideas?

Comment: If you have access to the XML, adding  xmlns:something="something" as an attribute on the first tag would fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different constructor on the XmlSlurper in order to get past parseText's validation/namespace awareness.   Try:

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(xmlObj.lensData).declareNamespace(something:'something')
```

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html