# namespace error parsing android xml with groovy

Tags: android, xml, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to read xml from the android manifest using Groovy (particularly `XmlSlurper` from `import groovy.xml.XmlUtil`), and I'm getting below from Gradle.

> Error:The prefix "android" for attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "activity" is not bound.

The code that results in that error is as follows:

```
def innerNodeTemplate = '''
                    <activity android:name=".activity.MyActivity"></activity>
                    '''
def activityNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(innerNodeTemplate)
```

I have tried declaring the namespace as follows ([from this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29265618/3570019))

```
activityNode = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(innerNodeTemplate).declareNamespace(android:'android')
```

but then I get a more explicit exception for the same namespace issue

> Error:Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 53; The prefix "android" for attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "activity" is not bound.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: There does not exist such namespace bounded in your xml. Why are you adding while parsing?

Comment: Hi Rao, "android:name" is in my xml. Do I need to add a declaration like xmlnx:android="" at the start of the xml snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rao pointed out, I was failing to bound the xml namespace.

The solution was adding `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to the root tag like so

```
def innerNodeTemplate = '''<activity android:name=".activity.MyActivity" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></activity>'''
activityNode = new XmlSlurper(false, true).parseText(innerNodeTemplate)
```

Afterwards there is no need to call `.declareNamespace( )`